# Where is the best place to store an RTCPeerConnection object in a React/Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, webrtc

RTCPeerConnection is an object with certain methods that when called mutate the object (for example, setLocalDescription, addIceCandidate). These methods get called based on received signaling from the other side of a WebRTC connection (like when you receive an offer, or an ice candidate).

Therefore, this object does not seem well-suited for being in a redux store, since the developer doesn't at a first approximation have control over the mutations, and in a redux reducer you can't just create a copy of an RTCPeerConnection as this would eliminate your previous webRTC session.

However, in a WebRTC app that uses React, perhaps different components need access to the RTCPeerConnection object (for instance, maybe it is instantiated on mount of the top level component in the app, but then in some UI component like a modal deep in the tree that accepts a call, you want to call a method on RTCPeerConnection to create an answer to the webRTC offer that was received. Or maybe a deeply nested component needs to initiate a call). Is it the case that the only solution is to pass the object as props down the component tree? Is there no way to use redux with a complex object like this?

UPDATE: considering the answer below about using middleware for handling socket.io, let me reframe my original question: would it make sense, if I have an RTCPeerConnection object as state in a top-level component, to build middleware that that handles dispatch calls that ultimately must receive some way some how a reference to the original RTCPeerConnection to make a method call such as `setRemoteDescription`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard place for "socket"-like connection objects (websockets, Firebase, etc) in a Redux app is in a middleware.  Any part of the application that needs to tell the socket to do something can dispatch an action that is intercepted by the middleware, and the middleware can dispatch actions to update the state in response to received messages.

There's dozens of existing examples of middleware for various sockets in the [Middleware - Sockets and Adapters](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware-sockets-adapters.md) section of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links).

**update**

Here's a quick example of what an RTC middleware might look like.  The code is completely untested, but this should illustrate the idea:

```
function createRtcMiddleware() {
    return (store) => {
        let rtcPeerConnection = null;

        return (next) => action => {
            switch(action.type) {
                case "RTC_CONNECTION_CREATE": {
                    const {rtcConfig} = action;
                    rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(rtcConfig);

                    rtcPeerConnection.somecallback = () => {     
                        // maybe dispatch a Redux action in response to 
                        // a received message                
                    };

                    // Do not pass the action down the pipeline, since only 
                    // this middleware cares about it
                    return;
                }
                case "RTC_CONNECTION_SET_DESCRIPTION": {
                    if(rtcPeerConnection) {
                        rtcPeerConnection.setDescription(action.description);
                    }

                    return;
                }
            }

            // If we don't care about it, pass it down the pipeline
            return next(action);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Really interesting answer, because I am also using socket.io, but it is only indirectly applicable to answering the question about a webrtc RTCPeerConnection object that is handling the receiving of "messages" internally.

Comment: Ah... I _think_ my answer is still valid and relevant to your question, but maybe I didn't state it clearly enough.  Lemme see if I can throw together some pseudocode to illustrate the idea.

Comment: @markerikson but what happens if you need to pass down the ui MediaStream instances from this middleware? since it's not serializable it's not good practice to save in Redux store

Comment: You could put it into a `<Context.Provider>` to pass it down the component tree. This may require restructuring the code so that the `rtcPeerConnection` variable lives in a separate module, creating the middleware assigns to that variable, and the provider component reads from that variable.

Comment: @markerikson I was thinking to create a component that renders a `<Context.Provider>` and as well as using a dynamic middleware with https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#addlistener, so I can benefit both worlds